# how to achieve the following task using sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two datasets. `Dataset1` have two variable `Name` and `Date`. `Dataset1` have `Name`, `Date2` and `Price`.

Dataset1 looks like the following

```
Name  Date
X1    2013-04-12
X1    2013-05-12 
X1    2014-04-12
X2    2012-06-11
X2    2014-04-12
X2    2015-05-01 
X3    2005-02-01
```

Dataset2 looks like the following

```
Name  Date1         price
X1    2013-04-11     1.1
X1    2013-05-12     2
X1    2014-04-13     3
X2    2012-06-13     2.2
X2    2014-04-12     0.6
X2    2016-05-01     0.5
```

For each `Name` and `Date` in `Dataset1`, I want to find the `price` of the same `name` with the most recent (latest) `date1` that equal or earlier than `Date` `dataset1.name = dataset2.name  and max(date1 |date1<= date)`.

Result should looks like:

```
Name  Date          Date1          price
X1    2013-04-12    2013-04-11     1.1
X1    2013-05-12    2013-05-12     2
X1    2014-04-12    2013-05-12     2
X2    2012-06-11    null           null
X2    2014-04-12    2014-04-12     0.6
X2    2015-05-01    2014-04-12     0.6
X3    2005-02-01    null           null
```

Can anyone teach me how to code this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, the easiest method is `outer apply`:

```
select d1.*, d2.*
from dataset1 d1 outer apply
     (select top 1 d2.*
      from dataset2 d2
      where d2.name = d1.name and d2.date1 <= d1.date
      order by d2.date1 desc
     ) d2;
```

Comment: This code will match with the most recent date1 conditional on date1 <= date?

Comment: Shouldn't d.name and d.date be d1.name and d1.date?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 [price] 
FROM Dataset1 
INNER JOIN Dataset2 ON Dataset1.[Name]=Dataset2.[Name]
WHERE [Date1] <= Date
ORDER BY Date1 DESC
```

This should do the trick